# Will moving a wordpress site create any problems with plugins?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently working on a wordpress site, and the folders are just such a mess, that I want to clean them up and make it a bit more bearable to look at. The site uses multiple plugins, and the main site is in a folder inside the httpdocs folder, which makes me wonder if the plugins will cause any problems by moving the site to the root.

Anyone that knows the answer to this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please have a look at some helpful tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - asking a good question improves your chances of getting an answer. 
But it is also equally important that you do some research before posting your question - for instance you could have just tried moving your site and see what happens. Also include what you have tried and indicate the problem(s) you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress uses a standard structure for plugins and themes. While these may be overwritten, it is not recommended to do so.

If you **really** wanna do so, you could take a look at this https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Moving_wp-content_folder for reference, and move it around. Remember that the plugin may use wordpress hooks and filters for adding their own CSS/JS, and thus moving the folder out of the web-directory will make these unavailable, and break the plugin functionality.